# Programmatically determine number of strokes in a Chinese character?

Tags: unicode, character-encoding, cjk

Does Unicode store stroke count information about Chinese, Japanese, or other stroke-based characters?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A little googling came up with [Unihan.zip](ftp://ftp.unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/Unihan.zip), a file published by the [Unicode Consortium](http://unicode.org/) which contains several text files including `Unihan_RadicalStrokeCounts.txt` which may be what you want. There is also an online [Unihan Database Lookup](http://www.unicode.org/charts/unihan.html) based on this data.

Answer (score 3):

In Python there is a library for that:

```
>>> from cjklib.characterlookup import CharacterLookup
>>> cjk = CharacterLookup('C')
>>> cjk.getStrokeCount(u'日')
4
```

Disclaimer: I wrote it

Comment: thanks for the great package! Today I tried it with these changes: 1. pip install cjklib3; 2. "C:\Users\your_name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib\site-packages\cjklib\util.py" needs a change to "from collections.abc import MutableMapping" from "from collections import MutableMapping"; 3. "cjk = characterlookup.CharacterLookup('C')" rather than "cjk = CharacterLookup('C')"

Answer (score 2):

You mean, is it encoded somehow in the actual code point? No. There may well be a table somewhere you can find on the net (or create one) but it's not part of the Unicode mandate to store this sort of metadata.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do character recognition goggle HanziDict.

Also take a look at the Unihan data site:

http://www.unicode.org/charts/unihanrsindex.html

You can look up stroke count and then get character info.  You might be able to build your own look up.

Answer (score 1):

UILocalizedIndexedCollation can be a total solution.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalizedIndexedCollation_Class/UILocalizedIndexedCollation.html

Comment: first, call 
"UILocalizedIndexedCollation sectionForObject:collationStringSelector:"
to get an index of section.

then back to check which section this index mapping to in "UILocalizedIndexedCollation.sectionTitles"

Comment: This is actually an Apple Eco-system only solution.