# How to get stroke count of Chinese character?

Tags: iphone, ios, nsstring, cjk

How to get stroke count of Chinese character?

Example>

一 => 1

十 => 2

日 => 4

Comment: Can you use a lookup table? http://technology.chtsai.org/charfreq/characters.html

Comment: See question [Programatically determine number of strokes in a chinese character](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2398334/programatically-determine-number-of-strokes-in-a-chinese-character).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: You can't without a hardcoded map of characters to stroke counts. And then, you'll have to assume the user is using a particular Chinese variant (e.g. traditional.)

Unicode (the basic character set used by `NSString`) doesn't distinguish between traditional, simplified, Japanese-specific, Korean-specific, etc. hanzi. Unicode does not encode stroke information directly. Rather, it distinguishes between *characters* (not their graphical representations) and a character may have different stroke counts depending on language and font used. So while the character 十 may universally have two strokes, other characters will vary.

The example Wikipedia gives is the character for "grass", U+8279, which has four strokes in traditional Chinese, but 3 in every other variant.

Comment: Is stroke count constant, if user set international settings? (like contacts app)

Comment: Maybe, but there still won't be an API for you to get the stroke count. There's no OS-defined `GetStrokeCount()` function or anything like that.

Comment: what wikipedia do you mean? according to my dictionary the traditional equivalent to the grass radical is 艸 (U+8278) vs 艹 (U+8279) in simplified, and traditional is more than four strokes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "ssc install cnstroke" STATA command for the said purpose.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Thanks, math.

First, call

```
NSInteger section = [[UILocalizedIndexedCollation currentCollation] sectionForObject:yourObject collationStringSelector:@selector(objectsProperty)];
```

then check index of section in following array

```
[UILocalizedIndexedCollation currentCollation].sectionTitles
```

Remember to add

```
Localized resources can be mixed = YES
```

in info.plist